# Single Event Handler for Multiple Events in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, openstreetmap, leaflet

Is it possible to create a trigger for multiple events in this manner?

```
map.on('click, dragstart, zoomstart', eventHandler);
```

If not what will be the next best way to trigger the same event handler for multiple events?

```
map.on('click', eventHandler);
map.on('dragstart', eventHandler);
map.on('zoomstart', eventHandler);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible, just remove the comma's:

```
map.on('click dragstart zoomstart', eventHandler);

function eventHandler(e) {
    console.log(e.type); //shows event type, i.e. "click", "dragstart" etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Is this something common to Javascript? Or just Leaflet

Comment: It's actually common to jQuery, as on() is a jQuery method.